# How can I generate a Flow based another Flow in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I know I can create a Flow based a `State<T>` variable  using `derivedStateOf` just like Code A, and `resultListAllMInfo` is `StateFlow<EResult<List<MInfo>>>` type.

Now I hope to get a `StateFlow<EResult<List<MInfo>>>` type based a Flow `_listSortBy` in Code B, how can I do?

BTW,  `_listMInfo`  is `Flow<StateFlow<EResult<List<MInfo>>>>` type in Code B.

**Added Content:**

Can I use Code C ? will `_listMInfo` be updated automatically when `_listSortBy` changed in Code C ?

**Code A**

```
class RecordSoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
): ViewModel() {

    var sortByState by mutableStateOf(ESortBy.START_PRIORITY)
        private set

    val resultListAllMInfo: StateFlow<EResult<List<MInfo>>> by derivedStateOf {
        handelMInfo.listAll(sortByState).stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), EResult.LOADING)
    }
}

fun listAll(eSortBy: ESortBy): Flow<EResult<List<MInfo>>>
```

**Code B**

```
class RecordSoundViewModel @Inject constructor(  
): ViewModel()
{  
    private val _listSortBy = MutableStateFlow(ESortBy.START_PRIORITY)

   //  _listMInfo  is Flow<StateFlow<EResult<List<MInfo>>>>
    private val _listMInfo = _listSortBy .map { handelMInfo.listAll(it).stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), EResult.LOADING)}

}
```

**Code C**

```
class RecordSoundViewModel @Inject constructor(  
): ViewModel()
{  
    private val _listSortBy = MutableStateFlow(ESortBy.START_PRIORITY)       
    private val _listMInfo = handelMInfo.listAll(_listSortBy.value)    
}
```

**Image 1**
[image]

Comment: Code A looks extremely fragile and I doubt it can work at all. When `sortByState` changes, the `derivedStateOf` will generate a new StateFlow, so all of the collectors of the previous flow will be collecting obsolete data. You have a `State<StateFlow>` which simply doesn’t make sense. Having a `Flow<StateFlow>` like in Code B also doesn’t make sense. It’s a cold flow of hot flows so the hot flows can never be shared by multiple collectors.

Comment: Thanks! Code A can work well, I have tested

Comment: I suspect your test may not be rigorous enough, because the code doesn’t make sense logically.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't fully understand what you mean but I think you are referring to merging between streams with flow so you can try this way.

```
    class RecordSoundViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel()
{
    private val _listSortBy = MutableStateFlow(ESortBy.START_PRIORITY)

    //  _listMInfo  is Flow<StateFlow<EResult<List<MInfo>>>>
    private val _listMInfo : Flow<EResult<List<MInfo>> = 
    combine(_listSortBy) { listSortBy ->
        // logic code
        // new list return here type EResult<List<MInfo>
        
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), EResult.LOADING)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I use Code C in my updated content?

Comment: Of course it's okay. combine allows to merge flows and bring them to a common result on a separate stream. When the flows in the combine have changes, the combine will automatically run again

Comment: BTW, your code doesn't work, myabe  combine( ) need to accept two parameters at least

Comment: combine accepts at least 1 parameter, it doesn't need to be 2. Please try the code and check again

Comment: Thanks, will `_listMInfo` be updated automatically when `_listSortBy` changed in Code C ?

Comment: And again, I have tested your code, it doesn't work

Comment: You need to explain to me the handelMInfo variable. I don't see it in your code

Comment: Ok I will write a simple example to help you understand this problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example when you want to use combine with flow

```
    enum class ESortBy{
    START_PRIORITY,NONE
}
val handelMInfo = listOf("abc","bcd")
class RecordSoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
): ViewModel()
{
    private val _listSortBy = MutableStateFlow(ESortBy.START_PRIORITY)
    private val _listhandelMInfo = MutableStateFlow(handelMInfo)
    private val _listMInfo : Flow<List<String>> = combine(_listSortBy,_listhandelMInfo){ sortType, listData ->
        //logic code
        //return new list type List<String>
        emptyList()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! your code doesn't work, you can see Image 1 in my updated question.

Comment: You need to convert handleMInfo into a flow form to combine with your sort. 
private val _listhandelMInfo = MutableStateFlow(handelMInfo)

Comment: Then you combine those two flows together and return any type of flow you want here I just for example Flow<List<String>> . You can replace it with Flow<Object> or Flow<List<Object >> you want